# How do I find the path of a template file using ERB?

Tags: ruby, erb

I am using embedded ruby (ERB) to generating text files. I need to know the directory of the template file in order to locate another file relative to the template file path. Is there a simple method from within ERB that will give me the file name and directory of the current template file?

I'm looking for something similar to `__FILE__`, but giving the template file instead of (erb).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the ERB api from Ruby, you provide a string to `ERB.new`, so there isn’t really any way for ERB to know where that file came from. You can however tell the object which file it came from using the `filename` attribute:

```
t = ERB.new(File.read('my_template.erb')
t.filename = 'my_template.erb'
```

Now you can use `__FILE__` in `my_template.erb` and it will refer to the name of the file. (This is what the `erb` executable does, which is why `__FILE__` works in ERB files that you run from the command line).

To make this a bit a bit more useful, you could monkey patch ERB with a new method to read from a file and set the `filename`:

```
require 'erb'

class ERB
  # these args are the args for ERB.new, which we pass through
  # after reading the file into a string
  def self.from_file(file, safe_level=nil, trim_mode=nil, eoutvar='_erbout')
    t = new(File.read(file), safe_level, trim_mode, eoutvar)
    t.filename = file
    t
  end
end
```

You can now use this method to read ERB files, and `__FILE__` should work in them, and refer to the actual file and not just `(erb)`:

```
t = ERB.from_file 'my_template.erb'
puts t.result
```

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this with erubis too

Comment: nvm, it is the same with erubis. just set `.filename = 'my_template.erb'`