# How to read a template file into a string?

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to use the template content as the body for a POST request.

```
body = IO::Read('templatefile') # ???
response = Chef::REST::RESTRequest.new(:POST, 'http://localhost:8080/createItem', body, nil).call
```

What is the proper way to do this? Most usage patterns for template involve creating files, not using the template for another method.

Note: Ideally, The solution would not even create a temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef templates weren't really designed to be used this way, but you might be able to do what you want by [finding the path of the template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290948/how-do-i-find-the-path-of-a-template-file-using-erb) and then [rendering the template by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954706/render-an-erb-template-with-values-from-a-hash).  You can use the rendered template text in your POST request.

Comment: I see, thanks! I ended up writing the template to a /tmp file

Answer (score 1):

I had once this issue in a cookbook.
Instead of putting such files into template subdir, I recommend you to put it into a file subdir (same level than recipes, tempaltes, ... subdirs). The reason is simple: as you said yourself, template subdir is not designed to store such files, hence it is considered a bad practice.

For instance, you can put your file `myfile` into `your_cookbook_dir/files/default/myfile`, expecting your cookbook directiry on your filesystem is named `your_cookbook_dir`.

Then, in you recipe, you can affect to a string the absolute path on the filesystem at runtime:

```
myfilepath = "#{run_context.cookbook_collection[cookbook_name].root_dir}/files/default/myfile"
```

At this point it becomes trivial to use the variable in another ruby instruction to read it!

I think this a better way (chef-design compliant) to adress your problem.

HTH.